# Perl script problems

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, initialization

The purpose of the script is to process all words from a file and output ALL words that occur the most. So if there are 3 words that each occur 10 times, the program should output all the words.

The script now runs, thanks to some tips I have gotten here. However, it does not handle large text files (i.e. the New Testament). I'm not sure if that is a fault of mine or just a limitation of the code. I am sure there are several other problems with the program, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
require 5.10.0;

print "Your file: " . $ARGV[0] . "\n";
#Make sure there is only one argument
if ($#ARGV == 0){

    #Make sure the argument is actually a file
    if (-f $ARGV[0]){

        %wordHash = ();     #New hash to match words with word counts
        $file=$ARGV[0];     #Stores value of argument
        open(FILE, $file) or die "File not opened correctly.";

        #Process through each line of the file
        while (<FILE>){
            chomp;
            #Delimits on any non-alphanumeric
            @words=split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/,$_);
            $wordSize = @words;

            #Put all words to lowercase, removes case sensitivty
            for($x=0; $x<$wordSize; $x++){
                $words[$x]=lc($words[$x]);
            }

            #Puts each occurence of word into hash
            foreach $word(@words){
                $wordHash{$word}++;
            }
        }
        close FILE;

        #$wordHash{$b} <=> $wordHash{$a};
        $wordList="";
        $max=0;

        while (($key, $value) = each(%wordHash)){
            if($value>$max){
                $max=$value;
            }
            }

        while (($key, $value) = each(%wordHash)){
            if($value==$max && $key ne "s"){
                $wordList.=" " . $key;
            }
            }       

        #Print solution
        print "The following words occur the most (" . $max . " times): " . $wordList . "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Error. Your argument is not a file.\n";
    }
}
else {
    print "Error. Use exactly one argument.\n";
}
```

Comment: please use pragma "use strict" in your scripts

Comment: consider http://www.66clouds.com/new_testament.html ;)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem lies in the two missing lines at the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

If they had been there, they would have reported lots of lines like this:

`Argument "make" isn't numeric in array element at ...`

Which comes from this line:

```
$list[$_] = $wordHash{$_} for keys %wordHash;
```

Array elements can only be numbers, and since your keys are words, that won't work. What happens here is that any random string is coerced into a number, and for any string that does not begin with a number, that will be `0`.

Your code works fine reading the data in, although I would write it differently. It is only after that that your code becomes unwieldy.

As near as I can tell, you are trying to print out the most occurring words, in which case you should consider the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %wordHash;
#Make sure there is only one argument
die "Only one argument allowed." unless @ARGV == 1;
while (<>) {    # Use the diamond operator to implicitly open ARGV files
    chomp;
    my @words = grep $_,           # disallow empty strings
        map lc,                    # make everything lower case
            split /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;  # your original split
    foreach my $word (@words) {
        $wordHash{$word}++;
    }
}

for my $word (sort { $wordHash{$b} <=> $wordHash{$a} } keys %wordHash) {
    printf "%-6s %s\n", $wordHash{$word}, $word;
}
```

As you'll note, you can sort based on hash values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entirely different way of writing it (I could have also said "Perl is not C"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

use List::Util qw(max);

my ($input_file) = @ARGV;
die "Need an input file\n" unless defined $input_file;

say "Input file = '$input_file'";

open my $input, '<', $input_file;

my %words;

while (my $line = <$input>) {
    chomp $line;

    my @tokens = map lc, grep length, split /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/, $line;
    $words{ $_ } += 1 for @tokens;
}

close $input;

my $max = max values %words;
my @argmax = sort grep { $words{$_} == $max } keys %words;

for my $word (@argmax) {
    printf "%s: %d\n", $word, $max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just get the keys from the hash sorted by their value and extract the first X?

this should provide an example: http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00016